# Why I can't stream YouTube's 4K resolution with a stable 200 Mbps internet connection?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

After changing ISPs YouTube's 4K resolution (and above) has buffered constantly, despite exceeding [Google's recommended internet speed](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3037019) (20 Mbps) for streaming video by tenfold. I now have a 200 Mbps plan, in the past I watched 4K on YouTube for years with a 100 Mbps connection. The exact same PC setup with the exception of the router. I've benchmarked and can download around 25 megabytes a second (200/8=25, see [data-rate units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-rate_units#Megabyte_per_second)).

In "stats for nerds" (right click on video) "network activity" seems to drop to around 200 KB sturing stuttering and "buffer health" to ~0 s.

Here is debug info, copied when playback stops, if that's relevant:

```
{
  "ns": "yt",
  "el": "detailpage",
  "cpn": "zaFsVKxW_95dB5HQ",
  "docid": "Zz82SNc__uI",
  "ver": 2,
  "referrer": "https://www.youtube.com/results?sp=EgJwAQ%253D%253D&search_query=cs%3Ago+danger+zone",
  "cmt": "4.275",
  "plid": "AAV8f2L9O27dAg6V",
  "ei": "Ro8LXNOUNsXHyAWl-ISYDg",
  "fmt": "315",
  "fs": "0",
  "rt": "8.787",
  "of": "ob1H7IDz41rRCQ3bd7XoBA",
  "euri": "",
  "lact": 3,
  "cl": "224297709",
  "mos": 1,
  "state": "9",
  "vm": "CAEQARgE",
  "volume": 100,
  "c": "WEB",
  "cver": "2.20181206",
  "cplayer": "UNIPLAYER",
  "cbr": "Firefox",
  "cbrver": "63.0",
  "cos": "Windows",
  "cosver": "10.0",
  "hl": "en_US",
  "cr": "FI",
  "len": "381.521",
  "fexp": "23710476,23721898,23733014,23735284,23744176,23744361,23744531,23749369,23750564,23751767,23752869,23753056,23755886,23755898,23760559,23760716,23762649,23764064,23769702,23769830,23770908,23771139,23772104,23774008,23774809,23776058,23777492,23778371,23780455,23780592,23781054,23781384,23782931,9407155,9413141,9441347,9449243,9471235,9471647,9485000",
  "afmt": "251",
  "vct": "4.275",
  "vd": "381.521",
  "vpl": "0.000-4.275,",
  "vbu": "0.000-8.008,",
  "vpa": "0",
  "vsk": "0",
  "ven": "0",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "2",
  "vns": "2",
  "vec": "null",
  "vvol": "1",
  "creationTime": 11022,
  "totalVideoFrames": 256,
  "droppedVideoFrames": 0,
  "corruptedVideoFrames": 0,
  "lct": "4.275",
  "lsk": false,
  "lmf": true,
  "lbw": "3642584.438",
  "lhd": "0.162",
  "lst": "0.000",
  "laa": "itag=251,type=3,seg=0,range=66462-131997,time=4.3-8.5,off=65536,len=65536",
  "lva": "itag=315,type=3,seg=1,range=15244413-21960083,time=5.1-7.2,off=0,len=6715671",
  "lar": "itag=251,type=3,seg=0,range=66462-131997,time=4.3-8.5,off=65536,len=65536",
  "lvr": "itag=315,type=3,seg=1,range=21960084-28675754,time=7.2-9.2,off=6715671,len=6715671",
  "lvh": "r5---sn-5go7yn7s",
  "lab": "0.000-8.481,",
  "lvb": "0.000-8.008,",
  "ismb": 6850000,
  "relative_loudness": "NaN",
  "optimal_format": "2160p60",
  "user_qual": "hd2160",
  "debug_videoId": "Zz82SNc__uI",
  "0sz": false,
  "op": "",
  "yof": false,
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "ANGLE_(NVIDIA_GeForce_GTX_780_Ti_Direct3D11_vs_5_0_ps_5_0)",
  "cgr": true,
  "debug_playbackQuality": "hd2160",
  "debug_date": "Sat Dec 08 2018 11:30:57 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)"
}
```